# trying to install python module(chatterbot) but shows error of visual studio 14 is required. not able to install visual studio

Tags: python-3.10, windows-11

When i try to install chatterbot module, it gives me an error saying -

"Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build preshed thinc blis
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error"

The issue is that when i try to install the visual studio, the application and even the setup file of buildtools just runs and then the application or anything doesn't gets installed.

I am on windows 11 and have only 1 drive that is C drive. Can someone please help me

I have tried it hundred times and with different settings such as -

1. trying to run as administrator
2. changing compatibility to windows 7 and 8 (windows 10 is not available)
3. running troubleshooter and then applying those setting
4. ran windows update troubleshooter and then applying the settings.

I am on windows 11 and have only 1 drive that is C drive. Can someone please help me